# Css animate/show div after other

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

How can I show 3 divs after each other with pure css3 in a loop ?

Firt div without dalay; second div; then third one:

That's what I have tried:

```css
    .text1 {
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-name: slidein;
        animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    }

    @keyframes slidein {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        25%,75%  { opacity: 100%; }
        100% { opacity: 100%;}
    }


    .animate-delay-3 { animation-delay: 3s;}
    .animate-delay-6 { animation-delay: 6s;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="header" class="header"></div>

        <div class="layer text1">
            <img src="div1.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="layer text1 animate-delay-3">
            <img src="div2.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="layer text1 animate-delay-6">
            <img src="div3.png" alt="">
        </div>

    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Think about the delay.  If it's 3s and the animation is 3s then they will sync up and always flash together.

Comment: Thanks Steven B. I have updated my code with  2 different delay classes but the second and the third div are always nit animated

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/5t3Lpfoq/) the desired effect?

Comment: The desired effect is to show 3 texts for a banner after each other. The user should have a little time to read the divs; at the end the 3 divs should be shown ca. 3 or 5 seconds; one by one...

Answer (score 0):

First of all *100%* is not a correct value for opacity, it should be a float between 0 and 1.

Also, we need to set *0* as initial value of opacity for every box.

If I understood you need the animation to run only once, so *animation-iteration-count* should be *1*.

Last thing, if we want the elements to stay visible after completing animation we shoud use *animation-fill-mode: forwards*.

Here we go:

```css
.text1 {
        animation-duration: 3s;
        animation-name: slidein;
        animation-iteration-count: 1;
        opacity: 0;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;  
    }

    @keyframes slidein {
        0% { opacity: 0; }
        25%,75%  { opacity: 1; }
        100% { opacity: 1;}
    }


    .animate-delay-3 { animation-delay: 3s;}
    .animate-delay-6 { animation-delay: 6s;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="header" class="header"></div>

        <div class="layer text1">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/80/80/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="layer text1 animate-delay-3">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/80/80/" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="layer text1 animate-delay-6">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/g/80/80/" alt="">
        </div>

    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, the animation have to play in a loop, but it's essentially much better now. It should be hidden after the third animation, and then repeated in an infinite loop.
I have changed it the animation-iteration-count: with infinite; but it looks strange now:
See my code here: https://codepen.io/Bizboss/pen/ROKLzg